# ServiceStack Stripe get all invoices with date filter

Tags: servicestack, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get all Stripe invoices with a date filter. At the moment the ServiceStack.Stripe package only allows for Date equality:

```
[Route("/invoices")]
public class GetStripeInvoices : IGet, IReturn<StripeCollection<StripeInvoice>>
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    public int? Offset { get; set; }
}
```

There are no options for "lt", "lte", "gt" and "gte".

In order to add these the request needs to look something like:

```
?date%5Blt%5D=1337923293
```

We can't use these special characters in a C# attribute name, so is there another way to override the class so that it serializes to match the request parameters required for date filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added support for Stripe DateOptions [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe/commit/4ec83af2769aec77a0e3f5e834b58404c98a30a7) where you can use use the new `DateOptions` property to specify a custom date, e.g you can specify a `lt` date with:

```
var response = gateway.Get(new GetStripeInvoices
{
    DateOptions = new StripeDateOptions {
        Before = DateTime.UtcNow
    }
});
```

The different Date Options available include:

```
public class StripeDateOptions
{
    public DateTime? After { get; set; }      //gt
    public DateTime? OnOrAfter { get; set; }  //gte
    public DateTime? Before { get; set; }     //lt
    public DateTime? OnOrBefore { get; set; } //lte
}
```

This change is available from v4.0.55 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Not very fan of 4 properties, it can be confusing if the user specifies several. What about StriperDateOptions { public DateComparison Operation {get;set;} public DateTime Date {get; set; } } // where DateComparison is an enum with GreaterThan, GreaterThanOrEqualTo...

Comment: @labilbe It's modelled closely after how it's implemented in Stripe's API, it's not trying to invent a new abstraction only for C# different to how every other Stripe library does it. Stripe could've designed their REST API differently so it's usage and surface area is more limited, but they designed it the way we did and we follow as closely we can with a typed 1:1 wrapper to make it easier to see how each property maps to Stripe's documented REST API.

Comment: Seems legit in fact.